# Is it possible to store the steps of a cucumber feature file in a java collection?

Tags: java, cucumber

I want to iterate trough a cucumber feature and store the scenarios on in a HashMap collection in java. I have tried to find out how but with no luck, can it be done? is there a tutorial or guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a direct way of getting access to the steps but you can try this workaround.

Pass the `Scenario` object to the `Before hook`. The Scenario object has two methods - `getUri()` which should give you the path to the feature file containing the currently executing scenario and `getLines()` which returns you a List of the line numbers of the current scenario.

You can then parse the feature file and fetch the relevant lines.

This should work in the latest cucumber version 1.2.5, though I have not tested it out. In older version you can look at the getName() and getId() methods of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `@Before` step, like this:

```
@Before
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    String scenarioName = scenario.getName();
    System.out.println("Scenario: " + scenarioName);
}
```

This will print the scenario name. You can easily add the name to a Hashmap. I've used `cucumber-java 1.2.5`.